# How to update a field in a table A with a count(fields) from another table B with condition of matchs (on sql server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm trying to update a field in table A with a number of occurences of some data in another table B. The condition is that the fiels in B must have the same foreign key as in the A table.
thank you in adavance

I wannt to make this count :”

```
select      COUNT(1) as NbrFacture,DateFacturation_FK, Site_FK, Client_FK
            from        DistrisysDW.dbo.FactFacture
            group by    DateFacturation_FK, Site_FK, Client_FK
            order by    2
```

“
AND  update “NbFacture” in the other table in condition that the rows match on this three fiels DateFacturation_FK, Site_FK, Client_FK.

I try this but it doesn’t work :

```
Update      DistrisysDW.dbo.FactFactureEntete
SET         NumFacture=T.NbrFacture
from        
            (select     COUNT(1) as NbrFacture,DateFacturation_FK, Site_FK, Client_FK
            from        DistrisysDW.dbo.FactFacture
            group by    DateFacturation_FK, Site_FK, Client_FK
            order by    2
            ) T
INNER JOIN  DistrisysDW.dbo.FactFactureEntete ENT ON T.DateFacturation_FK=ENT.DateFacturation_FK 
AND         T.Site_FK=ENT.Site_FK AND T.Client_FK=ENT.Client_FK
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the table alias in the `update` statement:

```
Update ENT
-------^
    SET  NumFacture = T.NbrFacture
from DistrisysDW.dbo.FactFactureEntete ENT inner join   
     (select     COUNT(1) as NbrFacture,DateFacturation_FK, Site_FK, Client_FK
      from        DistrisysDW.dbo.FactFacture
      group by    DateFacturation_FK, Site_FK, Client_FK
     ) T
     ON T.DateFacturation_FK = ENT.DateFacturation_FK AND
        T.Site_FK = ENT.Site_FK AND T.Client_FK = ENT.Client_FK;
```

The `order by` is unnecessary in the subquery.  I have a preference for putting the table being updated first in the `from` statement.  I find it easier to follow the logic.

Comment: u just forget the "inner join" after                                 from   DistrisysDW.dbo.FactFactureEntete ENT